# What's the Debian Equivalent for chkconfig

Tags: debian, systemd, services, systemctl, chkconfig

What's the Debian Equivalent for chkconfig?

On CentOS 6 I can run this to see the services that load with the system:

```
chkconfig --list
```

And i can set a service to start on boot like this:

```
chkconfig <service_name> on
```

Is there a similar binary that can do this for Debian?

To clarify I am using Kali rolling but from what I am told this is very similar to Debian

```
[kali@kali:~/labs/discovery]$ lsb_release -da
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:    2020.1
Codename:   kali-rolling

[kali@kali:~/labs/discovery]$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: kali
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: d74933508486479e9b07e83b9a036776
           Boot ID: ece90367d8454f7fb795b9f2f1787091
    Virtualization: vmware
  Operating System: Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
            Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-kali4-amd64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: What version of Debian are you referring to? Newer versions of Debian use systemd.

Comment: The equivalent to chkconfig is update-rc.d

Comment: Always take comment answers with a large pinch of salt.  The request for clarification shows why rubaiat's comment-answer is *at best* misleading.

Comment: @GMaster I updated the question with the operating system information.

Comment: For Kali 2020.1, my answer is correct

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your Debian system is running systemd, to check all enabled services equivalent to `chkconfig --list`:

```
systemctl list-unit-files --type=service --state=enabled
```

(As you can see from [What's the equivalent of chkconfig --list for systemctl?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/416253/5132), on CentOS 7 the `chkconfig` command has been updated to actually tell you this and anther systemd equivalent when it is run.)

To set a service to start on boot equivalent to `chkconfig <service_name> on`:

```
systemctl enable <service_name>
```

Comment: Always prefixing `sudo` is a bad habit in general, and is outright unnecessary in an answer like this one, given what `systemctl` does when invoked by a non-superuser.

Comment: Updated my answer. Thanks